# SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_AUDIO ) fails with -1

Tags: c++, audio, sdl-2

C++, SDL2, ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on a System76 Galago Pro. I have pulseaudio 13.99.1.

Trying to play a tone through the speakers using SDL2.

SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO) returns 0 and I can use the video and windowing systems.

SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO) returns -1, as does SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) after video is initialized.

If I ignore the error and proceed past this point to open and unpause the audio device, the audio callback never gets called.

```
void play_buffer(void* userdata, unsigned char* stream, int len) {
    printf("play_buffer never gets called\n");
}
SDL_AudioSpec spec = {
    .freq = 48000, 
    .format = AUDIO_S16SYS, // Signed 16 bit integer format
    .channels = 1,
    .samples = 4096, // The size of each "chunk"
    .callback = play_buffer, // user-defined function that provides the audio data
    .userdata = NULL // an argument to the callback function (we dont need any)
};
int main(){
    int sdl_error_code = SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
    printf("SDL error code: %i \n", sdl_error_code);
    SDL_AudioDeviceID dev = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &spec, NULL, 0);
    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(dev, 0);
}
```

This is not the whole program but just the relevant parts taken out and squished together for you to see.

Does anyone know what the error code means, and how to resolve it?

Comment: What does `std::cout << SDL_GetError() << '\n';` show?

Comment: Did you use SDL2 from the package manager or compiled it yourself?

Comment: @TedLyngmo inserting that line of code after SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO) appears to just print a new line, with no other characters.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I used SDL2 from the package manager.

Comment: @stanged That's odd. That means that not even SDL knows what went wrong. You did put it right after `SDL_Init(...);`, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes indeed, it is the immediate next line.

Can't say its unusual behavior for this computer! Appreciate your help though.

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling SDL2 and pulseaudio but it acted just the same.